# Casting AnyObject to Double

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to parse JSON with the following code:

```
    func ltchandler(response: NSURLResponse!, data : NSData!, error : NSError!) { //Is passed the results of a NSURLRequest

    if ((error) != nil) {
        //Error Handling Stuff
    } else {
        if (NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) == "") {

            //Error Handling Stuff
        } else {
            var data = NSData(data: data);

            // Define JSON string
            var JSONString = "\(data)"



            // Get NSData using string
            if let JSONData = JSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {


                // Parse JSONData into JSON object
                var parsingError: NSError?
                if let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parsingError) as? [String: AnyObject] {


                    // If the parsing was successful grab the rate object
                    var rateObject: Double! = JSONObject["price"]?.doubleValue

                    // Make sure the rate object is the expected type
                    if let rate = rateObject as? Double! { // THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!
                     //Do stuff with data   
                    } else {
                        println("Parsing Issue")

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }



}
```

The line marked `THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!` is not being called.

From what I can tell, it cannot cast rateObject as a double - why not? It is not showing any errors.

To clarify, the expected behavior is that a double is created from the JSON object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To strictly answer your question have you tried printing the rateObject. Also why are you casting to `Double!` rather than just `Double` in the problematic line?

Personally I don't use `!` in almost all cases. You are better off using either non-optionals or proper optionals.

In the relevent section I would write:

```
// Make sure the rate object is the expected type
if let rate = JSONObject["price"]?.doubleValue { 
    //Do stuff with rate
} else {
    print("Parsing Issue")
}
```

Of course if the `JSONObject["price"]` is not something with a `doubleValue` method or the method returns `nil` you will end up with nil and the else case being taken.

Comment: Thanks Rob, answer improved.

Answer (score 1):

the code worked for me, try this code:

```
// if the value equals nil or any String, the instruction abort the if
// SWIFT 2.0 in xcode beta 5
if let rate = Double((JSONObject["price"] as? String)!){ 
    // insert you code here   
} else {
    print("error message")
}
```